# how to split a string into 2 bytes by 2 bytes

Tags: c, string, split

How to split a string into 2 bytes by 2 bytes.I want to get time information as integer value from string.

```
char buffer[10]= "101507";

int hour = < 10
int min = < 15
int sec = < 07
```

Comment: What part(s) of this can you implement, and which do you need help with?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`sscanf()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), with specified field widths of `2` for each of your three variables:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[10] = "101507";
    int hour, min, sec;
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%2d%2d%2d", &hour, &min, &sec) != 3) {
        printf("Error reading data\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Hour = %02d, Min = %02d, Sec = %02d\n", hour, min, sec);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the calculation directly on the individual chars. Just subtract `'0'` to get the numerical value. Like

```
char buffer[10]= "101507";

int hour = 10 * (buffer[0] - '0') + (buffer[1] - '0');
int min =  10 * (buffer[2] - '0') + (buffer[3] - '0');
int sec =  10 * (buffer[4] - '0') + (buffer[5] - '0');
```

or write a simple function that takes two chars as arguments

```
int chars_to_int(char msd, char lsd)
{
    return 10 * (msd - '0') + (lsd - '0');
}


char buffer[10]= "101507";

int hour = chars_to_int(buffer[0], buffer[1]);
int min =  chars_to_int(buffer[2], buffer[3]);
int sec =  chars_to_int(buffer[4], buffer[5]);
```

or write a simple function that takes a char pointer as argument

```
int chars_to_int(char* p)
{
    return 10 * (p[0] - '0') + (p[1] - '0');
}


char buffer[10]= "101507";

int hour = chars_to_int(&buffer[0]);
int min =  chars_to_int(&buffer[2]);
int sec =  chars_to_int(&buffer[4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BARF(m) fprintf(stderr,"Barf: %s\n", m)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
unsigned val;
char *str = argv[1] ? argv[1] :"101507";
int hh,mm,ss;

for(val=0; *str; str++) {
        if (*str < '0' || *str > '9') {BARF(str); continue;}
        val *= 10; val += (*str - '0');
        }

ss = val % 100; val /= 100;
mm = val % 100; val /= 100;
hh = val % 100;

printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", hh, mm, ss);

return 0;
}
```